# Find a file in a directory which contains a certain sub-string

Tags: python

Let's suppose I have a directory with the following files:

```
01_this_file_en.txt, 01_23_this_file_fr.txt, 02_en.txt
```

How can I rename all the files that have "this_files" somewhere inside their name ?

Thanks.

Comment: Get a list of all filenames -> iterate over it -> if "this_files" in filename (or regex) -> rename the filename

Comment: Show us what you've tried so far, and explain which parts of your code are giving you trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script did work for me:

```
import os
for file in os.listdir(): #all the files in your directory
    if 'this_file' in file:
        os.rename(file, 'new_file.txt')
```

#### Update

I've just noticed there is a file collision. If you want to replace text in a file name instead of creating the same file repeatedly use:

```
os.rename(file, file.replace('this_file', 'new_file'))
```